# In Bash scripting, what's the meaning of " $! "?

Tags: bash, shell, variable

If I'm assigning a variable with

```
temp=$!
```

what would it be its value?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

`$!` contains the process ID of the most recently executed background pipeline. From `man bash`:

> #### Special Parameters
>
> The shell treats several parameters specially.  These parameters may only be referenced; assignment to them is not allowed.
>
> ...
>
> `!` - Expands to the process ID of the  most  recently  executed  background (asynchronous) command.

For example:

```
$ sleep 60 &
[1] 6238
$ echo "$!"
6238
```

Answer (score 33):

From Bash's man page:

```
   !   Expands to the process ID of the most recently executed 
       background (asynchronous) command.
```

So `$!` would contain the process ID (PID) of the last job that was backgrounded.

#### Example

```
$ sleep 100 &
[1] 18813

$ echo "$!"
18813
```

#### References

- [bash man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)