# `: &` in Shell Script

Tags: shell-script

I am trying to understand Ethan's shell script from [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/260798/502004), used to discover the maximum and minimum Process IDs on an OS.

```
pid=0
for i in {1..100000}; do
  : &
  if [ $! -lt $pid ]; then
    echo "Min pid: $!"
    echo "Max pid: $pid"
    break
  fi
  pid=$!
done
```

I know that `$` substitutes a shell parameter, and `!` is the [parameter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85022/597701) storing the PID of the "most recently executed background (asynchronous) command." Further, `&` is a [control operator](https://bashitout.com/2013/05/18/Ampersands-on-the-command-line.html) when used at the end of a command: whatever precedes is called in a background process. Thus, opening a new shell instance and running `: &`, followed by `$!`, we get:

```
% : &
[1] <PID>
[1]  + done       : 
% $!
<PID>
```

where `<PID>` varies each call. What does `if [ $! -lt $pid ]; then` do? Why does the script successfully vary from the minimum to the maximum PID (i.e, consistently outputs `100` and `99998`)? What is the final `pid=$!` for? Where does the counter `i` come into the script, if at all (other than repeating 100,000 times)?

Comment: Note that on a Linux, Windows, OpenBSD Sand probably most other systems, you don't see all processes, you see the processes of your process namespace (or how the equivalent is called on your OS) only. And depending on many factors, your processes might only be allowed a subrange of pids. So, the premise of that script seems questionable.

Comment: The fun thing with shells is that you can try all commands interactively. Run `echo {1..10}`, run `for i in {1..10}; do echo $i; done` to get the basics of the loop.

Comment: @nohillside the joy of interpreted programming! i didn't know about comparison operators and was more confused about what i thought was `-lt` being passed into `$!`.  that said, i did need to learn about [test constructs](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html) and their bracketing tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` is used just to run enough processes to try every possible PID in the range of the OS (some OS allow a bigger range of PIDs). Note this will start at an arbitrary point in the range, depending on how many processes have been run since booting.

`: &` runs a command that does nothing, but it gets allocated a unique PID (unique at the time it was started, anyway).

The script assumes that the OS allocates PIDs in increasing numeric order, skipping any in use. That's how many Unix-like OSes work, including Linux (by default). The script also assumes that the maximum process ID is less than 100000, which was true historically on Linux (15-bit PIDs) but is not true on modern Linux systems.

As long as the PID is greater than the highest we have yet seen, we store the new high and keep going.

When the OS runs out of PIDs, it will loop round and start from the lowest PID that is above the reserved range and not currently in use.

The first time that happens, we report the low PID we just got, and the highest before we wrapped round, and we are done.

Linux puts all the job control messages (thousands of them) to the terminal. I redirected the whole stdout output by changing the last line to:

```
done > /dev/null
```

and replacing the two echos to go to stderr with:

```
printf 1>&2 'Pid range: min %d, max %d\n' $! $pid
```

Comment: TIL about [comparison operators](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html) in shell scripts! Cheers

Comment: @shea  I can see you added a comment to a 7-year-old post. My Linux uses 300 to 32767. My lowest user pid is somewhere above 1500, so there are a *lot* of startup processes before I get to log-in. The rationale behind the 100 or 300 is probably that those low numbers will be root processes that will never exit until closedown, so don't even consider using them.